Can the Shape Operator be defined on arbitrary Riemannian manifolds?
While reading Chapter 15 of Needham's Visual Differential Geometry (picture of the passage at the end of the post) I came to wonder a couple of things:

What is the rigorous definition of the Shape Operator, and
Can the Shape Operator be defined on an arbitrary Riemannian submanifold $S$ of $M$?


Would the following be sensible?
Definition: let $S$ be a Riemannian submanifold of $M$. Given a unit normal vector field $n$ to $S$, the Shape Operator (with respect to a connection $\nabla$ of $M$) is defined as
$$s:TS\to TS:(p,v)\mapsto -(\nabla_vn)^\top.$$



What is "the" unit normal vector field to a Riemannian submanifold that has dimension different from two?

Yes but you need your submanifold to be a hypersurface for having a unique (up to sign) normal vector field

For a codimension $k$ submanifold, whose normal bundle is trivial, you can consider $k$ distinct orthonormal normal vector fields $n_1$,..., $n_k$, and consider the $k$ different shape operator associated to them.
